# Can I get a hint for this vector question?

Tags: vectors

> A small boat sails from a dock in the direction $N25E$ for $15km$ and then turns to $N58W$ for $12km$, and finally on a course of $S20W$ for $28km$. Find the distance and bearing of the yacht

I have worked out the distance to be $14.8443km$ but I can't get the bearing! I tried using the angle between two vectors of (let origin be $O$) **OC** and **OB** but I get a value outside the range of cos. I even tried to move up **OC** to form a triangle with **OA** and find the angle between **OA** and **OC'** but again to no avail. How can I do it?

Comment: I am not entirely familiar with your direction notation. Could you explain exactly what, say, N58W means?

Comment: @Arthur: This is compass bearing; face North, then turn $58^\circ$ towards the West. In true bearing/whole circle bearing, that is $302^\circ$.

Comment: It's compass bearing notation https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Trigonometry/Compass_Bearings

Comment: Try resolving the vectors into component vectors, then add the corresponding component vectors together, then find the bearing.

Comment: what do you mean by component vector

Comment: oh ok ill try that

Comment: When you write it in $\hat{i}, \hat{j}$ components, you should finally get to $(15 \sin25^0 - 12 \sin 58^0 - 28 \sin 20^0) \hat{i} + (15 \cos25^0 + 12 \cos 58^0 - 28 \cos 20^0) \hat{j}$ if you consider $\hat{i}$ East and $\hat{j}$ North. Once you do all the calculations, getting magnitude is simple, then take dot product with $\hat{j}$ and working from there to get to direction wrt North.

Comment: I have already found the magnitude to be $14.84$ but what do you take the dot project  $j$ with? I can find any relevant vector that produces a nice answer. I am trying to use the formula for angle between two vectors - is this incorrect then?